# Reading files from internal memory and loading to ImageView

Tags: android, view

In my app, saving the .jpg files in internal memory of mobile. and trying to load the same back in ImageView, for which doing the below thing..

```
        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        Bitmap bmp;
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        iView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

iView is Imageview instance.

But getting everytime bmp as null which means its not able to decode this file
Can anyone help how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I do it by getting Uri when creating the file and passing it to the bitmap like so:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageUri.getPath(), options);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

To get the Uri I do the following on the file:

```
imageUri = Uri.fromFile(fileNameHere);
```